# Flask application exits after returning exit code 0

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a basic "Hello world" program in Flask which exits without giving any output. The following is my code:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == "main":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
    print("test")
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But my http server is not starting, I get the following output:

```
$ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

Comment: may be `5000` occupied by another process. Try by giving other port:  `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)`

Answer (score 5):

When a `python` file is executed, the value of `__name__` is `"__main__"` and not `"main"`. Your code isn't entering into the `if` statement, which is why the `Flask` server never starts.

```py
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == "__main__":  # There is an error on this line
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
    print("test")
```

Comment: It resolved. Thanks for your help.